# Video View in alert custom

Tags: android

I'm using tablayout and in a TextView of the tablayout a personalized alert where I want to play the video.
I get an error when I upload the video, I get the alert Can not play this video.

The format the video is mp4

I think the error is loading the video or maybe finding it

```
public class MasaE_Male extends Fragment {

TextView Piernas, Pecho, Hombros, Espalda, Abdominales, p1, num1;
ImageView ivp1;
VideoView vp1;
ViewFlipper vf1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.masae_male,container,false);


    Piernas=view.findViewById(R.id.Piernas);
    Pecho=view.findViewById(R.id.Pecho);
    Hombros=view.findViewById(R.id.Hombros);
    Espalda=view.findViewById(R.id.Espalda);
    Abdominales=view.findViewById(R.id.Abdominales);


    Piernas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder BPiernas= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            View mView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.piernas,null);
            BPiernas.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog dialog =BPiernas.create();
            dialog.show();

            vp1=mView.findViewById(R.id.VV1);
            ivp1=mView.findViewById(R.id.IVp1);
            p1=mView.findViewById(R.id.textp1);
            num1=mView.findViewById(R.id.nump1);
            vf1=mView.findViewById(R.id.VFp1);

            String VideoPath= "android.resource://com.example.stark.finalp.Male" + R.raw.scb;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(VideoPath);
            vp1.setVideoURI(uri);

            MediaController MD= new MediaController(getActivity());
            vp1.setMediaController(MD);
            MD.setAnchorView(vp1);

        return view;
}
}
```

[error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulrZy.png)

Comment: what format is your video ?

Comment: the format is mp4